# How to fix owl carousel empty spaces after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, owl-carousel

I use the last version of [own carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)

I applied this slider on my [page](https://modesy.store/jewelry-accessories)

As you can see thre is a horizontal slider with circles. After click next button I get empty spaced on the owl stage.

As solution I tried to set negative `right` to the stage:

```
.owl-stage {
  right: -383px;
}
```

How to fix it?

[Screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spwj7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect occurs when `center` option is set as `true`, but `loop` option is disabled or set as `false`. For example:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    loop:false,
    ...
});
```

So There are two ways to avoid this effect:

1. Set both `center` and `loop` to `false`
2. Set both `center` and `loop` to `true`